# Using JiTouch with synergy

Tags: multi-touch

Is it possible to make Jitouch work with Synergy? Jitouch allows me to make gestures correspond to actions in different applications, but it doesn't allow me to select Unix programs (like the Synergy server) as a target.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that the Synergy server doesn't have an OS X frontend. I have the same issue with my Logitech mouse configuration -- I want to have a different scroll speed for Synergy because when I have acceleration enabled, the remote computer doesn't scroll properly. So I'd like to disable acceleration *only when using synergy*.

The solution would be to package `synergys` as an OS X app which, when you move your mouse to the remote computer, brings itself to the front (so that the menu bar contains only the Apple menu and a "Synergy" menu). [I have planned for a long time to create such a wrapper which would accomplish this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832158/how-to-activate-bring-to-front-in-rubycocoa) but just haven't had the time.

I didn't realize others would be interested in the same idea... If I ever complete that project I'll be sure to let you know! Or, maybe we should file a feature request with the synergy project? :-)